# What is the difference between :~: and :~~: equalities?

Tags: haskell, equality

In [`Data.Type.Equality`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html) there are two type-level equalities defined: `:~:` and `:~~:`. They are said to represent homogenous and heterogenous equality respectively, but I don't really see any differences between them. What is it?

To be honest I don't see a way for having a real heterogenous equality in Haskell type, due to the strict border between values, types and kinds in the typesystem.

Comment: A few papers: [A reflection on types](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~sweirich/papers/wadlerfest2016.pdf), [An overabundance of equality: Implementing kind equalities into Haskell](https://richarde.dev/papers/2015/equalities/equalities.pdf)

Comment: [`Type.Reflection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/Data.Typeable.Internal.html) requires heterogeneous equality

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward.

```
ghci> :k (:~:)
(:~:) :: k -> k -> *

ghci> :k (:~~:)
(:~~:) :: k1 -> k2 -> *
```

Note that [`Data.Type.Equality`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html) states that `:~~:` is "**Kind** heterogeneous propositional equality" (emphasis mine), so you need to look at the kinds.

Basically `:~:` is like term-level `==` in that using it requires that the two types you're checking equality for are members of the same kind. Types in different kinds (like terms in different types) are definitely not equal, but with `:~:` (like with `==`) you get pulled up for even contemplating the question.

But `:~~:` can be used even when you haven't established that the two types have the same kind. You won't be able to construct a `Refl :: a :~~: b` when the types (and thus the kinds) aren't equal, but GHC can contemplate the existence of the (empty) type `a :~~: b` when they don't have the same kind, unlike with `a :~: b`.

So you can use `:~~:` in some situations where you couldn't use `:~:`. But sometimes that flexibility is actually a problem. If you wanted the two sides to have the same kind, comparing them with `:~:` *adds* that information for the compiler (which might need it to resolve type class instances or type families or etc). If you use `:~~:` it says nothing about the kinds being equal except within the scope of an actual pattern match on the `Refl` constructor, so you might have to come up with another way to add the information about the kinds being equal if that's what you wanted.

Comment: What is the point of using `:~:` over `:~~:` then?

Comment: @radrow pretty much the same point as for most "why would I use stronger types" questions: it helps figuring out how to write your code and catching bugs early.

Comment: @radrow Well, for one thing it's just older. As the docs say, `:~:` dates to `base` 4.7, while `:~~:` only appeared in `base` 4.10. I don't know whether `:~~:` couldn't have been written in 4.7 yet or just nobody thought of it, but in 4.10 adding another type rather than changing the existing one avoids backwards incompatibility. But also, the very fact that `:~:` requires its arguments to be of the same kind *adds* that information to your program, and sometimes that's handy (for the same reason that `asTypeOf` is handy; merely linking two type/kind variables can be useful in and of itself).

Comment: @radrow Worth bearing in mind that by *far* the most common uses (I'm pretty sure, at least) will have both types of kind `Type`/`*`, so there's no *need* to support the kinds being different. A lot of the time it just won't make a difference which one you use, but very occasionally that'll be the only thing pinning down the kind of that variable for GHC and it will help resolve a type class instance or something. If you need the kind-heterogenous version you are probably doing something a little more advanced and hopefully will recognise that you need it.

Answer (score 12):

The difference is in their kinds:

```
type (:~:)  :: k  -> k  -> Type
type (:~~:) :: k1 -> k2 -> Type
```

The former only accepts two type arguments having the same kind, while the latter has no such restriction.

The type `Bool :~: Maybe` is ill-kinded (it will trigger a kind error), while `Bool :~~: Maybe` is well-kinded. The latter is empty, but at least we can write it without triggering errors.